# How to produce simple sliding window features over irregular time series in R?

Tags: r, time-series

If I have some multivariate irregular time series, such as zoo or xts objects with:

```
> clicks
           user item
2003-01-02    a    i
2003-01-03    a    i
2003-01-08    b    i
2003-01-09    a    j
2003-01-09    c    j
2003-01-10    b    j
> downloads
           user file
2003-01-08    a    f
2003-01-11    b    g
2003-01-11    b    f
> purchases
           user
2003-01-10    a
2003-01-16    b
```

I can write some code to produce a simple featurization of the above data into a data frame with a row per (user, day) for all days (up to the day of the user's first purchase), and with these columns:

- # clicks of item i in past 7 days
- # clicks of item i between 7 and 31 days ago
- # total past clicks
- same for item j
- same for downloads f, g
- whether a purchase occurs in the next 7 days

However, I'm curious whether there are easy, elegant, and not-painfully-slow ways to accomplish this using any of the various time series manipulation packages.  I looked around at things in zoo and xts but I didn't find anything promising.

Comment: I could swear I saw essentially this question a couple months ago, but can't find it.   Off the top of my head, `apply`-ing `diff` to the date column and selecting the matching data in the items column would seem to be pretty compact and quick.

Comment: Doesn't `rollapply` do what you want?

Comment: you can also look at `lubridate` and its duration or period classes.  But that needs a date vector rather than `zoo` or `xts` objects.

Comment: @gsk3 and upvoter: `rollapply` is one of the first functions I looked at.  It's limited to fixed-observation windows, whereas this question needs fixed-time.

Comment: Kind of clunky, but can't you just interpolate missings for days when you don't have an observation?  Then fixed-observation becomes fixed-time.

Comment: Rats.  I read the documentation differently.  Back to my `diff` thoughts.

Comment: @gsk3: Nope, the timestamps in reality aren't of daily granularity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can represent each type of event (e.g., "user A clicks item i")
as a time series `x`, with value 1 each time it occurs.
The quantities you are interested can be computed from `cumsum(x)`
(the number of events until today) and its translations 
(the number of events until k days in the past or the future).

```
# Sample data
set.seed(0)
k <- 100
users <- LETTERS[1:4]
files <- letters[1:4]
items <- letters[24:26]
clicks <- data.frame( 
  time = Sys.time() + runif(k, 0, k * 24 * 3600),
  user = sample( users, k, replace=TRUE ),
  item = sample( items, k, replace=TRUE )
)
clicks <- unique(clicks)
```

For a single time series:

```
x <- subset( clicks, user=="C" & item=="x" )
xts( rep(1,nrow(x)), x$time )
x <- xts( rep(1,nrow(x)), x$time )

y <- xts( coredata(x), index(x)+7*3600*24 )
z <- cbind(y, x)
z[ is.na(z) ] <- 0
cumsum(z[,2]) - cumsum(z[,1])
# cbind(x,z,cumsum(z[,2]) - cumsum(z[,1]))
```

For the whole dataset, you can use `ddply`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but see my comment above - you can't create a regular time series for this data because the events are not actually occurring on day-level granularity. And even if it were, sparsity would result in prohibitive resource usage. Sorry if the example data I sketched was misleading in this way.

Comment: The time series remain irregular. I have edited my answer to use times instead of dates to make it clear.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification! An immediate other issue is that there are millions of users, so looping over all of them and scanning the full table to select out relevant rows for each user is quite expensive. I'll accept your answer though since this might be as good as it gets without custom lower-level code.